# html canvas sets wrong color in strokeStyle

Tags: html, canvas, colors

Code:

```
$color_gradient.beginPath();
$color_gradient.rect(0, y-sel_radius, gradient_width, 2*sel_radius+1);
$color_gradient.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
$color_gradient.stroke();
$color_gradient.closePath();
```

Color of drawn rectangle is semitransparent despite that value of a is 1. How to remove transparency?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here: [Why is Javascript automatically blending my colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789339/why-is-javascript-automatically-blending-my-colors?rq=1)
But even after changing top and left by 0.5 color is semitransparent (but less).